# Xidel extract number/float

Tags: xpath, xidel

I would like to extract number/float value from this code using Xidel:

```
<p class="price">
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
        <bdi>
            304.00
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">
                €
            </span>
        </bdi>
    </span>
</p>
```

I am trying the following command:

```
xidel -s '<p class="price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"><bdi>304.00 <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">€</span></bdi></span></p>' -e "//p[@class='price']/translate(normalize-space(substring-before(., '€')),' ','')"
```

The translate command should replace space, but it's not working, in the output I still see one space after number "304.00_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to process the [no-break](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Help:Special_characters#ISO-8859-1_Characters) [space](https://github.com/Reino17/xivid/blob/52d496e2894f890b5a173f9b4e79accdbd2fef8a/xivid_notes.txt#L679-L685) separately with one of the following queries:

```
-e "//p[@class='price']/span/bdi/substring-before(text(),'&#160;')"
-e "//p[@class='price']/span/bdi/translate(text(),x:cps(160),'')"
-e "//p[@class='price']/span/bdi/replace(text(),'&#xA0;','')"
```

You can't use `normalize-space()`, because...

https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-normalize-space:

> The definition of whitespace is unchanged in [[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.1 Recommendation]](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#xml11). It is repeated here for convenience:
>
> ```
> S ::= (#x20 | #x9 | #xD | #xA)+
> ```

...it processes spaces, tabs, carriage returns and line feeds, but not no-break spaces:

```
xidel -s "<x>   test   </x>" -e "x'[{x}]'"
[   test   ]

xidel -s "<x>   test   </x>" -e "x'[{normalize-space(x)}]'"
[test]

xidel -s "<x>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</x>" -e "x'[{x}]'"
[   test   ]

xidel -s "<x>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</x>" -e "x'[{normalize-space(x)}]'"
[   test   ]

xidel -s "<x>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</x>" -e "x'[{translate(x,'&#160;','')}]'"
xidel -s "<x>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</x>" -e "x'[{replace(x,x:cps(160),'')}]'"
xidel -s "<x>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</x>" -e "x'[{replace(x,'&#xA0;','')}]'"
[test]
```

Btw, an alternative to get the price on that website:

```
xidel -s "https://kenzel.sk/produkt/bicykle/zivotny-styl/signora/" -e ^"^
  parse-json(^
    //body/script[@type='application/ld+json']^
  )//priceSpecification/price^
"
304.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the xpath expression to

```
-e  "substring-before(//p[@class='price']//bdi/normalize-space(.),' ')"
```

or

```
 -e "substring-before(//p[@class='price']//bdi/.,' ')"
```

or use `tokenize()`

```
 -e "tokenize(//p[@class='price']//bdi/.,' ')[1]"
```

The output should be

```
'304.00'
```

Comment: It works for the example above, but for some reason on the actual [website](https://kenzel.sk/produkt/bicykle/zivotny-styl/signora/) (with same code) not working. Weird.

Comment: @Adrian Weird indeed. Whatever that is on the actual website, it's not any of the regular space characters. Maybe someone smarter can figure that out. In the meanwhile, there is a way to retrieve that data, but it's very hacky. I can edit the answer, if you're interested.